# Migrating Sonarqube - Database Upgrade Error

Tags: sonarqube

We are trying to migrate Sonarqube 6.5 from EC2 to Kubernetes and our database is in AWS RDS.

Steps I followed:
1) Launched sonarqube pod 6.7 with an empty DB(e.g sonark8s).

2) Backed up and restored existing Prod DB to new DB (sonark8s).

3) Restarted the pod and executed  and then upgrade.

But, getting error 'Upgrade Failed: Database connection cannot be established. Please check database status and JDBC settings.'

web.log error:

2019.01.08 12:20:42 ERROR web[][DbMigrations] #1801 'Create table CE task characteristics': failure | time=18ms
2019.01.08 12:20:42 ERROR web[][DbMigrations] Executed DB migrations: failure | time=20ms
2019.01.08 12:20:42 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.DatabaseMigrationImpl] DB migration failed | time=64ms
2019.01.08 12:20:42 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.DatabaseMigrationImpl] DB migration ended with an exception
org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepExecutionException: Execution of migration step #1801 'Create table CE task characteristics' failed
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:79)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:67)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:590)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:52)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.engine.MigrationEngineImpl.execute(MigrationEngineImpl.java:50)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.DatabaseMigrationImpl.doUpgradeDb(DatabaseMigrationImpl.java:105)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.DatabaseMigrationImpl.doDatabaseMigration(DatabaseMigrationImpl.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute CREATE TABLE ce_task_characteristics (uuid VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,task_uuid VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,kee VARCHAR (512) NOT NULL,text_value VARCHAR (512) NULL, CONSTRAINT pk_ce_task_characteristics PRIMARY KEY (uuid)) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange$Context.execute(DdlChange.java:97)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange$Context.execute(DdlChange.java:77)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange$Context.execute(DdlChange.java:117)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.version.v66.CreateTableCeTaskCharacteristics.execute(CreateTableCeTaskCharacteristics.java:67)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange.execute(DdlChange.java:45)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:75)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'ce_task_characteristics' already exists

Comment: Try the following steps: Install SonarQube 6.7.6 LTS, update database connection in config, restore the SonarQube 6.x database, start SonarQube and start upgrade 6.x => 6.7.6.

Comment: I solved it! Started sonarqube with an empty DB and then created one more DB and backed it up with data and then moved the sonarqube from empty DB to the new DB and then upgrade. It worked.